# Custom Persistence class for python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram, mongoengine, python-telegram-bot

I am developing a simple Telegram chat bot using `python-telegram-bot` library. My bot is currently using the `ConversationHandler` to keep track of the state of the conversation.

**I want to make the conversation persistent by storing the conversation state in a MongoDB database**.

I am using `mongoengine` library for python to communicate with my DB.

By reading the documentation for `BasePersistence` (https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.basepersistence.html) I understood that is necessary to extend this class with a custom one, let's call it `MongoPersistence`, and to overwrite the following methods:

- `get_conversations(name)`
- `update_conversation(name, key, new_state)`

The documentation doesn't specify the structure the `dict` returned by `get_conversations(name)` has and so it's also difficult to understand how to implement `update_conversation(name, key, new_state)`

Suppose I have the above mentioned class (`store_user_data`, `store_chat_data`, `store_bot_data` are all set to `False` because I don't want to store this data):

```py
from telegram.ext import BasePersistence


class MongoPersistence(BasePersistence):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MongoPersistence, self).__init__(store_user_data=False,
                                               store_chat_data=False,
                                               store_bot_data=False)

    def get_conversations(self, name):
        pass

    def update_conversation(self, name, key, new_state):
        pass
```

How can I implement this class so that my conversation state will be fetched and saved from the DB?

Answer (score 10):

### Conversation Persistence

I guess the simpliest way to implement it is looking at `PicklePersistence()`.
The only example I've seen of the dictionary is `conversations = { name : { (user_id,user_id): state} }` where `name` is the one given to `ConversationHandler()`, the tuple-as-a-key `(user_id,user_id)` is the `user_id` to whom your bot is talking to and `state` is the state of the conversation. Ok, maybe one isn't `user_id`, maybe is `chat_id` but I can't say for sure, I need more guinea pigs.

To handle the tuple-as-a-key, python-telegram-bot includes some tools to help you handle that: `encode_conversations_to_json` and `decode_conversations_from_json`.

Here, `on_flush` is a variable to tell the code if you want to save everytime there is a call to `update_conversation()` when is set to `False` or only when exiting the program when is set to `True`

One last detail: for now the following code only saves and retrieve from the database but *there is no replacing nor deleting*.

```
from telegram.ext import BasePersistence
from config import mongo_URI
from copy import deepcopy
from telegram.utils.helpers import decode_conversations_from_json, encode_conversations_to_json
import mongoengine
import json
from bson import json_util

class Conversations(mongoengine.Document):
    obj = mongoengine.DictField()
    meta = { 'collection': 'Conversations', 'ordering': ['-id']}

class MongoPersistence(BasePersistence):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MongoPersistence, self).__init__(store_user_data=False,
                                               store_chat_data=False,
                                               store_bot_data=False)
        dbname = "persistencedb"
        mongoengine.connect(host=mongo_URI, db=dbname)
        self.conversation_collection = "Conversations"
        self.conversations = None
        self.on_flush = False

    def get_conversations(self, name):
        if self.conversations:
            pass
        else:
            document = Conversations.objects()
            if document.first() == None:
                document = {}
            else:
                document = document.first()['obj']
            conversations_json = json_util.dumps(document)
            self.conversations = decode_conversations_from_json(conversations_json)
        return self.conversations.get(name, {}).copy()

    def update_conversation(self, name, key, new_state):
        if self.conversations.setdefault(name, {}).get(key) == new_state:
            return
        self.conversations[name][key] = new_state
        if not self.on_flush:
            conversations_dic = json_util.loads(encode_conversations_to_json(self.conversations))
            document = Conversations(obj=conversations_dic)
            document.save()

    def flush(self):
        conversations_dic = json_util.loads(encode_conversations_to_json(self.conversations))
        document = Conversations(obj=conversations_dic)
        document.save()
        mongoengine.disconnect()
```

**BEWARE!** Sometimes the conversations requires to user previosly setted `user_data` and this code doesn't provide it as requested.

### All Persistence

Here is a more complete code (*still lack the replace document in the database*).

```
from telegram.ext import BasePersistence
from collections import defaultdict
from config import mongo_URI
from copy import deepcopy
from telegram.utils.helpers import decode_user_chat_data_from_json, decode_conversations_from_json, encode_conversations_to_json
import mongoengine
import json
from bson import json_util

class Conversations(mongoengine.Document):
    obj = mongoengine.DictField()
    meta = { 'collection': 'Conversations', 'ordering': ['-id']}

class UserData(mongoengine.Document):
    obj = mongoengine.DictField()
    meta = { 'collection': 'UserData', 'ordering': ['-id']}

class ChatData(mongoengine.Document):
    obj = mongoengine.DictField()
    meta = { 'collection': 'ChatData', 'ordering': ['-id']}

class BotData(mongoengine.Document):
    obj = mongoengine.DictField()
    meta = { 'collection': 'BotData', 'ordering': ['-id']}

class DBHelper():
    """Class to add and get documents from a mongo database using mongoengine
    """
    def __init__(self, dbname="persistencedb"):
        mongoengine.connect(host=mongo_URI, db=dbname)
    def add_item(self, data, collection):
        if collection == "Conversations":
            document = Conversations(obj=data)
        elif collection == "UserData":
            document = UserData(obj=data)
        elif collection == "chat_data_collection":
            document = ChatData(obj=data)
        else:
            document = BotData(obj=data)
        document.save()
    def get_item(self, collection):
        if collection == "Conversations":
            document = Conversations.objects()
        elif collection == "UserData":
            document = UserData.objects()
        elif collection == "ChatData":
            document = ChatData.objects()
        else:
            document = BotData.objects()
        if document.first() == None:
            document = {}
        else:
            document = document.first()['obj']

        return document
    def close(self):
        mongoengine.disconnect()

class DBPersistence(BasePersistence):
    """Uses DBHelper to make the bot persistant on a database.
       It's heavily inspired on PicklePersistence from python-telegram-bot
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super(DBPersistence, self).__init__(store_user_data=True,
                                               store_chat_data=True,
                                               store_bot_data=True)
        self.persistdb = "persistancedb"
        self.conversation_collection = "Conversations"
        self.user_data_collection = "UserData"
        self.chat_data_collection = "ChatData"
        self.bot_data_collection = "BotData"
        self.db = DBHelper()
        self.user_data = None
        self.chat_data = None
        self.bot_data = None
        self.conversations = None
        self.on_flush = False

    def get_conversations(self, name):
        if self.conversations:
            pass
        else:
            conversations_json = json_util.dumps(self.db.get_item(self.conversation_collection))
            self.conversations = decode_conversations_from_json(conversations_json)
        return self.conversations.get(name, {}).copy()

    def update_conversation(self, name, key, new_state):
        if self.conversations.setdefault(name, {}).get(key) == new_state:
            return
        self.conversations[name][key] = new_state
        if not self.on_flush:
            conversations_json = json_util.loads(encode_conversations_to_json(self.conversations))
            self.db.add_item(conversations_json, self.conversation_collection)

    def get_user_data(self):
        if self.user_data:
            pass
        else:
            user_data_json = json_util.dumps(self.db.get_item(self.user_data_collection))
            if user_data_json != '{}':
                self.user_data = decode_user_chat_data_from_json(user_data_json)
            else:
                self.user_data = defaultdict(dict,{})
        return deepcopy(self.user_data)

    def update_user_data(self, user_id, data):
        if self.user_data is None:
            self.user_data = defaultdict(dict)
        # comment next line if you want to save to db every time this function is called
        if self.user_data.get(user_id) == data:
            return
        self.user_data[user_id] = data
        if not self.on_flush:
            user_data_json = json_util.loads(json.dumps(self.user_data))
            self.db.add_item(user_data_json, self.user_data_collection)

    def get_chat_data(self):
        if self.chat_data:
            pass
        else:
            chat_data_json = json_util.dumps(self.db.get_item(self.chat_data_collection))
            if chat_data_json != "{}":
                self.chat_data = decode_user_chat_data_from_json(chat_data_json)
            else:
                self.chat_data = defaultdict(dict,{})
        return deepcopy(self.chat_data)

    def update_chat_data(self, chat_id, data):
        if self.chat_data is None:
            self.chat_data = defaultdict(dict)
        # comment next line if you want to save to db every time this function is called
        if self.chat_data.get(chat_id) == data:
            return
        self.chat_data[chat_id] = data
        if not self.on_flush:
            chat_data_json = json_util.loads(json.dumps(self.chat_data))
            self.db.add_item(chat_data_json, self.chat_data_collection)

    def get_bot_data(self):
        if self.bot_data:
            pass
        else:
            bot_data_json = json_util.dumps(self.db.get_item(self.bot_data_collection))
            self.bot_data = json.loads(bot_data_json)
        return deepcopy(self.bot_data)

    def update_bot_data(self, data):
        if self.bot_data == data:
            return
        self.bot_data = data.copy()
        if not self.on_flush:
            bot_data_json = json_util.loads(json.dumps(self.bot_data))
            self.db.add_item(self.bot_data, self.bot_data_collection)

    def flush(self):
        if self.conversations:
            conversations_json = json_util.loads(encode_conversations_to_json(self.conversations))
            self.db.add_item(conversations_json, self.conversation_collection)
        if self.user_data:
            user_data_json = json_util.loads(json.dumps(self.user_data))
            self.db.add_item(user_data_json, self.user_data_collection)
        if self.chat_data:
            chat_data_json = json_util.loads(json.dumps(self.chat_data))
            self.db.add_item(chat_data_json, self.chat_data_collection)
        if self.bot_data:
            bot_data_json = json_util.loads(json.dumps(self.bot_data))
            self.db.add_item(self.bot_data, self.bot_data_collection)
        self.db.close()
```

Two details:

1. Chat_data persistence hasn't been saving to the database for now. Needs more testing. Maybe that part of the code has a bug.
2. For now the only part of the code where `on_flush = False` works is in Conversations. In all other updates it seems the call is done after the assignment so `if variable[key] == data` is always `True` and finish the code earlier than saving to database, that's why there is a comment saying `# comment next line if you want to save to db every time this function is called` but makes a lot of savings. If you set `on_flush = True` and the code stops earlier (the process is killed for example) you won't save anything on the database.